# Windows Search equivalent to Indexing Services "vpath" and "characterication"

Tags: indexing-service, windows-search

I'm trying to move a website that was on:

- **Windows 2003**,
- **IIS 6**, and
- **Indexing Services**

to:

- **Windows 2008**,
- **IIS 7**, and
- **Windows Search**

It's Windows Search that's giving me a problem.  I've set up a Windows Search to index the physical folder that contains the site, and I can query for file names, but what is the new equivalent of `vpath` and `characterization`?

[None of these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ff521735(v=vs.85)) seem to be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

characterization = System.Search.AutoSummary

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-search-autosummary)

Answer (score 1):

Query the "directory","filename" properties from the Indexing Service. Then, using ASP Classic / VbScript, with RS representing a recordset:

```
Function MapURL( Path )
' opposite of server.mappath - takes a filesystem path and turns it into a url
     Dim AppPath
     AppPath = Server.MapPath("/")
     path =  Replace(path,apppath,"",1,-1,1)
     path =  Replace(path,"\","/",1,-1,1)
     MapURL = path
End Function

Dim vpath
do while not rs.EOF
   vpath = rs("directory")  & "/" &  rs("filename")
   response.write MapURL(vpath)
   rs.movenext
loop
```

Based on ASP.NET code from http://geekswithblogs.net/AlsLog/archive/2006/08/03/87032.aspx